# this.select() not working on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I am working on a website and i want to select all text on the focus of a textbox. I write this code `onfocus="javascript:this.select();"` on the textbox. Its working in all browsers of desktop but its not working in ipad.

How can we implement this.select() or select textbox value in ipad?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to make select work's on iPad you need to do that :

```
function selectedText(t){
   setTimeout(function(){
      t.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
   },1);
}

$("input").each(function(){
   $(this).bind('focus',function(e){
      selectedText(e.target);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the OP _really_ need to pull in jQuery to get this working?

Comment: Nop you can do this out of jquery.
with : document.getElementById('yourid').addEventListener('focus',selectedText,true);
or onfocus="selectedText(this);return false;"

Comment: My point being: Why did you suggest that the OP pull in jQuery if it's not necessary? If there is a reason then please explain it, preferably by showing solutions both with and without so that the OP and future visitors can decide for themselves.